# How to get List of items from Begin to Specific item of another list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have a List like this

```
             var s = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
            {
                new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", "t1"}, {"age", 12}},
                new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", "t2"}, {"age", 22}},
                new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", "t3"}, {"age", 32}},
                new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", "t4"}, {"age", 42}},
                new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", "t5"}, {"age", 52}},
                new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", "t6"}, {"age", 62}},
            };
```

how i can get a list that items including from first to item that name = "t4"

the result list must like this :

```
            new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
            {
                new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", "t1"}, {"age", 12}},
                new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", "t2"}, {"age", 22}},
                new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", "t3"}, {"age", 32}},
            };
```

Comment: Seems to me like you have chosen the wrong data type to begin with. Instead of a `Dictionary<string, object>` you should probably use a designated class or at least a tuple (value tuple if you are working with c#7 or higher)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netframework-4.7.2) for this kind of operation:

```
var result = source.TakeWhile(s => s["name"] != "t4").ToList();
```

Comment: Please note that this would require the list to be sorted by the dictionary name.